# Website Being Scraped Requires Human Navigation (no login)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape the following page:

http://www.ferdinand-hodler.ch/werke.aspx?id=6006188

If you cannot see the content of the page, welcome to the club. It redirects me to the main page, then when I first click a book on the main page, and then click "Works" (or Werke in German) and then click a picture, it finally allows me to use the individual links to enter other pages.

I tried to set the headers but it worked only temporarily. (Now it's not working although I renew it.)

Any solution?

My code so far.

```
headers = {
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=ovakll55jo1wgo55mpizx2eg; sikart=de; _ga=GA1.2.868599919.1540663052; _gid=GA1.2.1406101683.1540663052"
}
s = requests.Session()
page = s.get("http://www.ferdinand-hodler.ch/werke.aspx?id=6006188"
,headers=headers)
file = page.content
print("Provenienz" not in str(file)) # I need this to be true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the site need valid cookie to show you desired page.

For the first time your link showed list of books, but, after that, clicking on it showed the desired page.

So:

1) Make first request to the main page of the site, and remeber returned cookie

2) Make second request with cookie, acquired on the first stage

Comment: yes this seems to be working. I don't know why they had such a design decision. Right now I'm using the same session and getting link to pretend to be navigating the site and it is fine.

Comment: This is because of some strange magic inside of asp. I have problems with authorization to the user's personal account on asp website. In the login form it added several hidden fields with some information, and that fields should be sent with login and password to make success. Otherwise authorisation just doesnt happen without any errors or information.